# Java JNDI Delete entire LDAP subtree

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, openldap

I need to delete entire LDAP subtree, by Java code, like the -r parameter of ldapdelete command. How can I do that? 
Is there a simple way to delete entire LDAP subtree with JNDI?

Answer (score 0):

Usually deleting entire subtrees in LDAP is something you do only in tests...

Anyway,there's a utility class in spring-Ldap test utils called LdaptestUtils that does just what you want. I won't copy the code here. Take a look at http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/ldap/spring-ldap/1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-ldap-1.3.0.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/ldap/test/LdapTestUtils.java?format=ok

The relevant method name is clearSubContexts() (note the overloading).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `javax.naming.ldap.TreeDelete` control, if your server supports it, otherwise you have no choice but to do it by hand, depth-first.